# What is the highest density to be measured?

Tags: density

In the abstract of the recent article named
"Transport properties and equation of state for HCNO mixtures in and beyond the warm dense matter regime"
we can read that authors measured a density of 36.8 g/cm3 for a mixture of a CHON fluid.
Link here
http://journals.aps.org/pre/accepted/2e07fRe7S461bf1fb6d03058699a2d6d35725e1e9
Diamond, lead, gold... even at high pressure have a density of 10 g/cm3. How it can be possible to have a density of something higher than the bomb used to measure it ?

Comment: $\uparrow$ On Earth?

Comment: I don't know what the *"warm dense matter regime"* is, but finding out would be step 2. Right after making the obvious **"they've discovered fruitcake!"** joke.

Comment: what do you mean by bomb? That doesnt make sense

Comment: Also golds density is more like 19 g/cm^3

Comment: A bit of googling provided a partial answer.   The article you quoted is about warm dense matter (WDM) - not to be confused with WMD for anyone who's dyslexic like me.   WDM is matter in an extreme state, a few tens of thousands of kelvin.   It's density can reach 100 g/CM, but that's cause it's so hot, the electrons aren't stable (er, I think).  Short article here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warm_dense_matter   Longer here: http://www-als.lbl.gov/index.php/research-areas/time-resolved/657-ultrafast-spectroscopy-of-warm-dense-matter.html

Comment: Did they used a Bomb, I mean a container, to measure such a density, 36.8 g/cm3? More a particule accelerometer? Also if they measured it at high temperature, how must be the pressure, kind of nuclear force?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the question directly, I believe nuclear transparency studies via heavy ion collisions provide a measure of highest recorded density. That would be several times nuclear density $\rho_0$, where $\rho_0\approx 2.5\times 10^{14}~{\rm g/cm^3}$.

Comment: Well that beats my example; ICF devices routinely reach 1 kg/cm^3